# Dimensions and their Measurements.

Tags: geometry

The basic measurements are, well, basic:

> A line had Length
>   A square has Area
>   A cube has Volume

But my question is simply, what goes in the ?s in the next list?

> A tesseract has ?
>   A penteract has ?
>   A ? has ?

Do anybody know? I'm sort of lost. Can't find anything on the Internet.

Comment: As a side note, the 4th dimensional analogue of "up" and "down" is "ana" and "kata". These terms was coined by Charles Hinton. I thought this might interest you, but decided to write it in a comment since it doesn't directly answer your question.

Comment: @Guri Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no agreed-upon term for the 4D analogue of Volume.

Mathematicians would either use "4D-Volume" or "Hypervolume", the latter being the term they'll use for any number of dimensions above 3.

Comment: Alright can you answer the other part in the question? What comes after the penteract?